# Windows 8 Store App in Kiosk mode and MS Word documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, windows-8.1, kiosk-mode

Tried looking for an answer on here, but didn't find anything asking about the type of issue I have.

I am interested in building a Windows 8.1 Metro/Store app that would use a web service to pull a list of relevant MS Word documents (.docx extension).  The app must run in kiosk mode.  At the same time, the user needs to be able to select a Word document in app and read the Word document.

My understanding is that in a normal Windows 8 Store app, I can simply open a Word document using MS Word.  However, is this still possible in Kiosk mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.
Out of the box, winrt provides api for PDF documents. You can have something on your server to convert word to pdf and after display it.